# Почему js функции запускаются почти одновременно

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Есть две функции

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateGridView() {
        LoadingPanel.Show();
        $("form#form-grid-partial-view-refresh").ajaxSubmit({
            url: '@Url.Action("GridViewPartial")',
            asynk: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#partialViewDiv').html(html);
                LoadingPanel.Hide();
            }
        });
    }

    function toExcel() {
        updateGridView();
        $("form#form-grid-partial-view-refresh").submit();
    }

</script>
```

`updateGridView` выполняет обычный поиск и выводит результат

`toExcel` выполняет поиск выводит результат и выгружает его в эксель

При вызове функции `toExcel` я ожидаю что вначале выполнится поиск через `updateGridView`, потом пойдет выгрузка в эксель, но этого не происходит. А получается что вызывается урл из `updateGridView` и сразу же (не дожидаясь результата) вызывается субмит для выгрузки в эксель. Почему так ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что запрос выполняется ассинхронно, напиши
async: false

Answer (score 1):

Да, в js функции асинхронны. Используй async/await

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.5.0/async.min.js"></script>
// или npm 

<script>    
    async function toExcel() {
        var result = await updateGridView();
        $("form#form-grid-partial-view-refresh").submit();
    }
</script>
```